# sklearn train test split, Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [13, 1]

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
import sklearn
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def standard_units(table, column):
  value = table.column(column)
  mean = np.mean(value)
  std = np.std(value)
  lst = []
  for x in range(len(value)):
    val = (value[x] - mean)/std
    lst.append(val)
  return lst

label = 'target'
features = ['age', 'sex', 'cp', 'trestbps', 'chol', 'fbs', 'restecg', 
                      'thalach', 'exang', 'oldpeak', 'slope', 'ca', 'thal']

suheart = heart.with_columns('age', standard_units(heart, 'age'),
                             'trestbps', standard_units(heart, 'trestbps'),
                             'chol', standard_units(heart, 'chol'),
                             'thalach', standard_units(heart, 'thalach'),
                             'oldpeak', standard_units(heart, 'oldpeak'))

print(suheart)
X = suheart.select(features)
y = suheart.select(label)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
```

I keep getting this error and I dont know whats wrong,

X and y have the same amount of rows.

I want to split the Table into a train and test variable

`ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [13, 1]`